# Jersey servlet exception tomcat jersey

Tags: maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, jersey

I'm having an issue trying to Deploy servlet to Tomcat using maven;
I've been reading about this issue in other posts but still couldn't succeed with the answers/suggestions.

I'm getting this Exception no matter what i'm trying:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   root cause
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>       com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is my web.xml file :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>
    com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
    </param-name>
    <param-value>com.rest.example
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm.jar</artifactId>
    <version>20041228.180559</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle.jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server.jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core.jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <type>pom.lastUpdated</type>
</dependency>
```

The sum.java file

```
package com.rest.example;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class sum {
@Path("/hello")

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayHello() 
{
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

And just in case :

[image: and the project itself]

I've tried cleaning and building it again but still no change;
What am i missing ? thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Error Message:

> The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.rest.example</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The above tells Jersey to scan the `com.rest.example` package for classes annotated with `@Provider` and `@Path` so that it can register them. The error is telling you that no resource classes registered during application load. Reason:

```
public class sum {
@Path("/hello")
```

The `@Path` annotation should go on *top* of the class definition, not *below*. Jersey found no resource classes, because the there is no `@Path` annotation on the class.

Answer (score 0):

I got quite the same problem, even with this setting and went into a
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-servlet] threw exception
caused by
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14877

The problem was in the end that I wasn't concrete enough with the package and my project went to big in the home package directory.
Be aware and gather all endpoints in a package separated in the project.